# What is the proper way to return a value from try-catch block?

Tags: java, exception

An example that does not work due to the lack of a return value:

```
public Path writeToFile() {
    try {
        Path tempFilePath = Files.createTempFile(Paths.get(""), "sorting_test_", ".txt");
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempFilePath.toFile()));

        for (List<Integer> arr : arrays) {
            // Convert array ints to strings, join it to single string and write
            bw.write(arr.stream()
                    .map(String::valueOf)
                    .collect(Collectors.joining(" ")));
            bw.newLine();
        }
        bw.close();

        return tempFilePath;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I know that I can do like this:

```
public Path writeToFile() {
    Path tempFilePath = null;
    //try-catch{...}
    return tempFilePath;
}
```

But it looks ugly. Is there a more natural way to solve this task?

Comment: There is nothing that says you can only have a single return statement.  why not just return the path if you have it.  If the catch block is encountered, just `return null` at the end.  But try/catch blocks are necessary if not elegant.

Comment: Add `return null;` after the `catch`?

Comment: I wouldn't say it looks "ugly", especially because it's the only way (at least that I know of) you can access a variable outside of the scope of a try-catch block. That's just Java's, along with many other programming languages', rules for scope of a try-catch.

Comment: Don't catch the exception! The problem disappears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some possible solutions:

- Change the method signature to `public void writeToFile()`.  Don't return the `Path`. (But this probably won't work for you: you probably *need* the `Path`.)
- Add `return null;` at the end of the method.  This has the disadvantage that the caller needs to deal with the case where `null` is returned ... or else it will get NPEs when they attempt to use the non-existent `Path`.

  This is equivalent to your "ugly" solution.  It is debatable which is better from a stylistic perspective.  (A dogmatic "structured programming" person would say your way is better!)
- Change the signature to return as `Optional<Path>`.  This is a better alternative than returning an explicit `null`.  If you implement it correctly, the caller is effectively forced to deal with the "absent" case.
- Remove the *try catch* and change the signature of the method to `public Path writeToFile() throws IOException`.  The caller has to deal with the checked exception, but that may be a good thing!

---

I should point out that your code is not handling the resources properly.  You should be using *try with resources* to ensure that the stream created by `FileWriter` is *always* closed.  Otherwise there is a risk of leaking file descriptors that could ultimately result in unexpected I/O errors.

Comment: Yep, you are right. `Optional` is evolution of try-catch syntax. This is what I'm looking for.

Comment: "Optional is evolution of try-catch syntax." - I wouldn't have described it as that.  `Optional` and `try`/`catch` are orthogonal and serve different purposes.  If anything `Optional` is an evolution of `null`.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to return `null` i will prefer using `Optional` from java 8

```
public Optional<Path> writeToFile() {
    try {
        Path tempFilePath = Files.createTempFile(Paths.get(""), "sorting_test_", ".txt");
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempFilePath.toFile()));

        for (List<Integer> arr : arrays) {
            // Convert array ints to strings, join it to single string and write
            bw.write(arr.stream()
                    .map(String::valueOf)
                    .collect(Collectors.joining(" ")));
            bw.newLine();
        }
        bw.close();

        return Optional.of(tempFilePath);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   return Optional.empty()
}
```

So in the caller method you can use

> public void ifPresent(Consumer consumer)

or

> public boolean isPresent()

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you're looking for a more "natural" solution, but you could just `return null` in your catch block.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, instead of eating an `IOException` (antipattern), convert it to an appropriate subclass of `RuntimeException` and throw from the catch block.

Also, in your example, you are leaking file handler, by not closing `FileWriter` on exception.

```java
public Path writeToFile() {

    final Path tempFilePath;
    try {
        tempFilePath = Files.createTempFile(Paths.get(""), "sorting_test_", ".txt");
    } catch (IOException e ) {
        throw new MyRuntimeException(
                "Cannot create sorting_test temp file",
                e
            );
    }

    try (final FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(tempFilePath.toFile())) {
        try(final BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw)) {
            for (List<Integer> arr : arrays) {
                // Convert array ints to strings, join it to single string and write
                bw.write(arr.stream()
                    .map(String::valueOf)
                    .collect(Collectors.joining(" ")));
                bw.newLine();
            }
        }

        return tempFilePath;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new MyRuntimeException(
                "Cannot write to " + tempFilePath,
                e
            );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you are right about leaking file handler. But your code isn't compiliable. First of all we can't do: `writer = bw;` because `writer` is final. Also `Path tempFilePath = Files.createTempFile...` must be inside try-catch block because it throws an exception. And the main question was how to return the value from try-catch block in differ way not about exceptions.

Comment: @standalone You are right about exception handler around `tempFilePath` creation.  I've updated my answer.  However you are not correct about `writer = bw;`, because writer is NOT `final`

Comment: Did you compile your code? `Error:(135, 13) java: auto-closeable resource writer may not be assigned`

Answer (score 0):

The most appropriate way is to keep the return statement in try block.

If we keep the return statement in finally or after catch we might be swallowing the exception.

[This is an old link that seems to be related. See if this helps.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25280665/java-where-to-put-return-in-try-catch-finally-block)